# database design for three tables...class ,teacher and student

Tags: mysql

i have tables as  teacher and student
teacher table has

```
id    teacherName    classAssigned
1          tea1                 1
2           tea2            1
3           tea3            3
4           tea4        2
```

student table has

```
id      name        class
1       st1              1
2       st2              1
3       st3              3
4       st4              4
```

I used the left join query….
As

```
SELECT  student1.name , teacher1.name
       FROM student1 LEFT JOIN teacher1 ON student1.class = teacher1.class where student1.class=1

Student_name         Teacher_name
St1         tea1
St1         tea2
St2         tea1
St2         tea2
```

now i want the Result as

```
class       TeacherNo     Student_no
1             2                       2
```

because there is two teachers for two students in class 1..IM GETTING THE COUNT AS 4

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT )` to count the students and teachers, something like this:

```
SELECT 
  student1.class,
  COUNT(DISTINCT student1.name)        AS studentno , 
  COUNT(DISTINCT teacher1.teacherName) AS Teacherno
FROM student1 
LEFT JOIN teacher1 ON student1.class = teacher1.classAssigned 
where student1.class = 1
GROUP BY student1.class;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30167e/4).

This will give you:

```
| CLASS | STUDENTNO | TEACHERNO |
---------------------------------
|     1 |         2 |         2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend try this query it will count the teacher name and student name whose class=1

```
SELECT  class , Count(teacher1.name) as TeacherNo, Count(student1.name) as Student_no
       FROM student1 LEFT JOIN teacher1 ON student1.class = teacher1.classAssigned where student1.class=1
```